# Reshape table so that dates are sequential in columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, reshape

I have a simple table like this:

```
| ID | Time1 | Time2 | Time3 |
|----|-------|-------|-------|
| 1  | 2005  |       |       |
| 2  | 2003  | 2004  | 2005  |
| 3  | 2004  |       |       |
| 4  | 2003  | 2005  |       |
| 5  | 2005  |       |       |
```

Is there a moderately painless way to reshape this table and end up with a table like this?

As you can see, I want to arrange the values that are poorly formatted within the 3 `TimeN` columns so that they are ordered in a sequence, and there are null values where dates don't exists.

```
| ID | Time1 | Time2 | Time3 |
|----|-------|-------|-------|
| 1  |       |       | 2005  |
| 2  | 2003  | 2004  | 2005  |
| 3  |       | 2004  |       |
| 4  | 2003  |       | 2005  |
| 5  |       |       | 2005  |
```

I think there must be a simpler way than my currently expanding 50 lines of horrible MySQL.

Comment: Please define "spread my data". How?

Comment: How many columns do these years span?  Is it something manageable like 6 or like 50?

Comment: A picture of a markdown formatted table is worth a thousand words! Regardless, I edited the question.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones: I only have 10 columns. It will take 100 years for there to be 110 columns! :D

Comment: Normalise your schema

Comment: @Strawberry I'm working with a temp table here

Comment: In which case, more explanation is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mystical SQL statement that will do this.

You will need a SQL statement that assigns values to each of the columns, something like this:

```
 UPDATE mysimpletable t
    SET t.Time1 = expr
      , t.Time2 = expr
      , t.Time3 = expr
```

I recommend you work on building a new table first. Get a SELECT statement that returns the result you are after.

This will be easiest if you can identify which value will go in each column. If 2003 is your lowest value, and you want that to appear in Time1 column if that value appears in any of the TimeN columns, each value fixed to a specific column, something like this:

```
 SELECT s.id
      , IF('2003' IN (s.Time1,s.Time2,s.Time3),'2003',NULL) AS Time1
      , IF('2004' IN (s.Time1,s.Time2,s.Time3),'2004',NULL) AS Time2
      , IF('2005' IN (s.Time1,s.Time2,s.Time3),'2005',NULL) AS Time3
   FROM mysimpletable s
  ORDER BY s.id
```

If that returns the result you are after, assuming the id column is a non-null unique key, I'd do a:

```
 CREATE TABLE newtable (PRIMARY KEY (id)) AS SELECT ...
```

Once I was sure that was right, only them would I perform the update.

```
 UPDATE newtable s
   JOIN mysimpletable t
     ON t.id = s.id
    SET t.Time1 = s.Time1
      , t.Time2 = s.Time2
      , t.Time3 = s.Time3
```

This approach should work for the example data. But again, this assumes that we know that 2003 will be the value stored in Time1, and 2004 is the value stored in Time2, etc.

There might be an easier, simpler way. But this is the approach I would take... I'd go at it with a SELECT statement first, developing the expressions that return the value for each of the columns. Then create a temporary work table from that SELECT. And then after making certain that it's what I want, I'd do the UPDATE, using the work table as the source.

But I'd also be questioning why the table is designed the way it is, making it a requirement to perform this type of update in the first place.

Comment: Great answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: ...especially the final paragraph